# Create multiple QwtPlotCurve dynamically

Tags: qt, qwt

I have a `QStringList (m_NameList)` which contains 4 elements in it. For each string, I create a `QwtPlotCurve (QMap < QString, QwtPlotCurve*>  m_NamePlotC;)` and set different Pens for each plotCurve:

```
for(unsigned int i= 0; i< m_NameList.count(); ++i)
{
  QwtText title(m_NameList.at(i));
  title.setFont(fontNormal);

  m_NamePlotC[m_NameList.at(i)]= new QwtPlotCurve();
  m_NamePlotC[m_NameList.at(i)]->setTitle(title);

  if(i== 0)
  {
    m_NamePlotC[m_NameList.at(i)]->setPen(QPen(Qt::green, 1, Qt::DashLine));
  }
  else if(i== 1)
  {
    m_NamePlotC[m_NameList.at(i)]->setPen(QPen(Qt::blue, 1, Qt::DashLine));
  }
  else if(i== 2)
  {
    m_NamePlotC[m_NameList.at(i)]->setPen(QPen(Qt::cyan, 1, Qt::DashLine));
  }
  else if(i== 3)
  {
    m_NamePlotC[m_NameList.at(i)]->setPen(QPen(Qt::yellow, 1, Qt::DashLine));
  }

  m_NamePlotC[m_NameList.at(i)]->setRenderHint(QwtPlotItem::RenderAntialiased, true);
  m_NamePlotC[m_NameList.at(i)]->setCurveAttribute(QwtPlotCurve::Fitted);
}
```

My problem is with the getting rid of `if`-statements. Is there any creative way that I set pens dynamically based on the number of `QStringList` elements with different color for each element in my `QStringList`, without using `if`s?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in each line, the only thing changing is the colour. You can maintain a list of colours, let's call it `coloursList` and then replace the `if`s by

```
m_NamePlotC[m_NameList.at(i)]->setPen(QPen(coloursList[i], 1, Qt::DashLine));
```

I'm not sure which language you have used, so my indexing syntax may be a bit off, but I hope the logic is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I am using c++. I did it as you said and it works:

```
QStringList m_ColorList;
m_ColorList<< "orange";
m_ColorList<< "green";
m_ColorList<< "cyan";
m_ColorList<< "yellow";
m_ColorList<< "magenta";
m_ColorList<< "blue";
m_ColorList<< "white";
m_ColorList<< "gray";
m_ColorList<< "red";

m_NamePlotC[m_NameList.at(i)]->setPen(QPen(QColor(m_ColorList[i]), 1, Qt::DashLine));
```